# C# How to Print 2 arrays together

Tags: c#, arrays, console

Ok, so lets say i have two arrays like these;

```
int[] wow = new int[50];
            for (int j = 0; j < wow.Length; j++)
            {
                wow[j] = j + 1;

            }
            int[] wew = new int[50];
            for (int i = 0; i < wew.Length; i++)
            {
                wew[i] = i + 10;

            }
```

and i want to print them like;

```
1 , 11
2 , 12
3 , 13
```

Comment: What have you tried? What about using the same `for` loop that you use for array initialization and one of the [`Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aakt1eab(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads - `Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", wow[i], wew[i]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < wow.Length; j++)
{
     wow1[j] = j + 1;
     wow2[j] = j + 10;
     //print wow1 & wow2 here. 
     Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", wow1[j], wow2[j]);
}
```

Note that in your two loops, i is no different with j, they are essentially the same!

Answer (score 0):

How about using two for-loops?

```
for(int i = 0; i < wow.Length;i++)
{
        for(int j = 0; j < wew.Length;i++)
        {
            //Print
            Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", wow[i].ToString(), wew[j].ToString());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in case both arrays are the same length

```
for (int i=0; i<wew.Length; i++)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(wow[i] + ", " + wew[i]);
 }
```

If the length is different more logic is needed